# React hook form read most up to date input value

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a form made using react hook form. It's a simple checkbox.
[image]

Everytime this value is checked or unchecked (onchange) I want to read out the value. Is there a possibility with react-hook-form to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-hook-form custom onChange handler in checkbox -> change is not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68661390/react-hook-form-custom-onchange-handler-in-checkbox-change-is-not-registered)

Answer (score 1):

Give the checkbox a name and watch it with the `watch` property of the `useForm` hook. Like `const newsLetterWatch = watch("subscibeToNewLetter", false);`. Attaching code sandbox for a better understanding. I have given an initial value here. If you don't want that, you can use the `useEffect` hook to get the real-time value of each `register'ed field.

Refer: [React Hook form - Watch](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch), [Set default values in React Hook Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70663158/set-default-values-in-react-hook-form), [React-hook-form custom onChange handler in checkbox -> change is not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68661390/react-hook-form-custom-onchange-handler-in-checkbox-change-is-not-registered)

[image: Edit React Hook Form (JS) (forked)]